# How to show list of products in google assistant without selecting any of them?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, chatbot

Currently i am building a chatbot where i need to display list of products with its description. I tried Carousel, Browsable Carousel and List but they all allow to select any options from the list.

I want to display the products but do not allow to select any of them.
[image]

I am using dialogflow as NLP and sending fulfillment using action-on-google's dialogflow node.js library.

Can anyone help me implementing this ?

Comment: What are you expecting the user to do next?

Comment: I will be giving suggestions to trigger different intents. Here i only want to show products as information purpose

Answer (score 2):

You can try sending a single [Basic Card](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#basic_card) with an image, if that is suitable for the response. You can also look into using a [Table Card](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#table_card), however it doesn't allow for images in the cells - just a single image for the table.

There is no way to prevent a List or Carousel item from being selected, but you can certainly handle the response by ignoring what they've selected and re-prompting them with whatever you've prompted them with after showing the carousel/list. (Or even just re-showing the list and re-prompting them.)

However, it really isn't clear why the items are for information only and that speaking them isn't intended to continue the conversation. Would it make sense that, if a user selected one, you might provide additional information that can be useful? What would a user expect?

Comment: currently the purpose of bot is to show products for information only. I can implement the process that you've mentioned but that's no point implementing action_intent_OPTION intent for same details of product after selecting list option. Really struggling to find the solution. However facebook has carousel option that has both the options ( selectable or unselectable )